# Not Getting Interface In android app using AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am working on a game in android. I want to display my interface which contains some images. I have a folder in assets named gfx .This folder contains images. I Have written this code .

public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

```
private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mTowerTextureRegion, mRing1, mRing2, mRing3;
private Sprite mTower1, mTower2, mTower3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    //return null;
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
        ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
            }
        });
        // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM
        backgroundTexture.load();
        towerTexture.load();
        ring1.load();
        ring2.load();
        ring3.load();

     // 3 - Set up texture regions

        this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
        this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
        this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
        this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
        this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        Debug.e(e);
    }

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);

    // 2 - Add the towers
    mTower1 = new Sprite(192, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower2 = new Sprite(400, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower3 = new Sprite(604, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(mTower1);
    scene.attachChild(mTower2);
    scene.attachChild(mTower3);
    return scene;

}
```

}

But only getting hello world on screen which is written in xml.
I have noticed that onCreateResources() and onCreateScene() are not called. Do they need to be called explicitly?

Can anyone help me??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect your interface to look like?

Comment: I suggest that you break down your app into smaller chunks. What is the smallest possible amount of code that you can get working to do part of your game?

Comment: @monad , actually lines inside the onCreateResources() and onCreateScene() are not executing. Seems that these functions are not being called.

Comment: If you want to combine some android components and AndEngine's GLSurfaceView, you should consider to extend your activity from `LayoutGameActivity` or `SimpleLayoutGameActivity`. You should not call AndEngine's callback methods (onCreateResources, onCreateScene...) directly, and these callbacks are called when AndEngine's GLSurfaceView is setup correctly. However, in your above code, your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in onCreate may probably do the wrong thing... Did you have AndEngine's GLSurfaceView (`RenderSurfaceView`) inside your xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't wired all the parts of AndEngine together correctly. I suggest that you start [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/eclipse-andengine-and-helloworld-t380.html) for information about how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing android activity with andengine activity.

This all about activity life cycle which is different for both andengine and android